# how to calculate the Standard Normal distribution of a sample in R

Tags: normal-distribution

I generated a random sample of size $n=10$ from $N(\mu ,\sigma)$ with $\mu =100$ and $\sigma =10$, say $x_1 ,\ldots ,x_n$ and arrange them from the smallest to the largest in R as follows:

```
n=10
mu=100
sigma=10
x=rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
x=x[order(x)]
```

Then I estimated $\mu$ and $\sigma$ by their MLEs $\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}$ and $S=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i -\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$, respectively, by `mean(x)` and `sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / (n - 1))`.

My question is that: how can I compute the statistic $\delta =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|z_i -\frac{i}{n}|}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\max (z_i ,\frac{i}{n})}$ in $R$, where $z_i =\phi (\frac{x_i -\bar{x}}{S})$.

---

Is this True?

```
for (i in 1:10){y[i]=x[i]-mean(x)/S}
dnorm(y,0,1)
```

Comment: I think the only crucial point is that $z_{i}$ can be calculated with the use of ```dnorm(y,0,1)``` where $y=\frac{x_{i}-\bar{x}}{S}$

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Thank you so much for the comment. Is my answer true?

Comment: You can check if my answer works for what you want

Comment: As a heads up, the $S$ you gave is not a maximum likelihood estimator of standard deviation, even if it is the common estimator of standard deviation. The MLE would haave $n$ in the denominator, not $n-1$.

Comment: This post belongs on [SO] but an attempt to migrate it there was rejected because you are blocked from asking questions.  Please don't use CV as a way to circumvent the system block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer would be

```
z = c()
for(i in 1:n){
 z[i] = dnorm((x[i]-mean(x))/S,0,1)
}
num = 0 
for(i in 1:n){
 num = num + abs(z[i]-i/n)
}
den = 0
for(i in 1:n){
 den = den + max(z[i],i/n)
}

delta = num/den
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works properly. One more question, I was wondering if you could tell me  how  I can compute the $((1-\alpha)\times 100)^{th}$ percentile of the null distribution of $\delta$ at $n$ that satisfies $P(\delta >\delta_{\alpha ,n}|H_0 )=\alpha$ in R for some $\alpha$?

Comment: @M.Ramana I would love to help you but I'm not an expert on that topic :/

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention.